# With which countries do we use 'The'?

Tags: definite-article, proper-nouns

If someone lives in USA he'd say,

> I live in the United States Of America.

But if someone lives in India, he would not say,

> I live in the India.

The better way seems to say,

> I live in India.

So what is the rule to decide with which country do we use *The*?

Comment: Wikipedia has a good explanation about the definite article with geographical names : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_articles#Geographical_names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You usually use "the" with countries whose names include words like kingdom, states, or republic  such as The Kingdom of Saudi Arabia, The United States, The United Kingdom, The Republic of China, etc.  We also use the definite article with countries which have their names as plural nouns such as The Philippines, The Netherlands, etc.

Answer (score 3):

We use "The" where the name refers to an area that is a collection of some kind, or a structure of some kind. What do I mean by this?

> I lived in **China** vs ***The* People's Republic of China**
>   I lived in **America** vs ***The* United States of America**

There are some notable exceptions such as *The Netherlands*, which is because it refers to the Kingdom of the Netherlands. You'll notice that other countries don't follow this though. It's mostly a matter of convention, which will change over time, as it has with *The Ukraine*, which no longer uses the article.

Unfortunately, these countries just have to be learnt individually.

Comment: By area do you mean that the place might not actually be a country but just a specific area.

Comment: Sometimes, but some countries are specific areas as well. The Bahamas, for instance. And some countries were previously _just_ certain areas.

Comment: A big clue is _of_ or an adjective before the country name. _The_ United Kingdom. But then, you also get _Great_ Britain.

Comment: So the _the_ is fixed in the country's name itself?

Comment: Should I write "_If someone lives in USA he'd say,_" Or "_If someone lives in **the** USA he'd say,_"

Comment: The second is more acceptable to me but I'm sure people use the first.

Comment: There are exceptions: 'I lived in the Gambia' or 'I lived in the Sudan' are both in use (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gambia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudan - third line second para)